# Ajax JSON response to C# array/list

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, ajax

I have a piece of JavaScript code to use my own API, what I want to do now is convert the ajax response to a C# list or array instead of appending the data to a table as example, what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://localhost:44326/api/intranet",
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $("<tr><td>" + data[i].UrlName + "</td><td>" + data[i].GroupName + "</td><td>" + data[i].Url + "</td></tr>").appendTo("#data");
                }
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**The response:**

[image]

So, as you can see I'm looping through the data and appending it to a table on my webpage. But as explained above, I want it to be converted to a list or array.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is to e converted ?

Comment: @RayonDabre a JavaScript array of data, the ajax response.

Comment: could you please share your Response Data

Comment: Since you are looping through your response, is it not already in an array/collection?  What type does your API function return?

Comment: @SatishSam It's there now.

Comment: @monstertjie_za it is, but I want it to be stored in a C# array/list.

Comment: @Peurr so you want to convert in your JQuery code, your current array, to a C# Array?  Not sure why you would want to do this.  If you are wanting to send this array back to your server side code, you can just send it back as is, and on your server side, declare your parameter as an YourType[] array.

Comment: how can you store data in C# array/list at client end?????   C# array/list is a server side object.

Comment: @SatishSam not at the client end, I just want it to be saved in a variable in my MVC controller..

Comment: as i understand you are getting response from a `API` and want to store same response data in `MVC` Controller.. is it

Comment: @SatishSam that's indeed what I want.

Comment: so there is a several ways to do so. 1.  you need to create a `web method`   which take a param. call that web method by ajax and send JS object from param and at the the server end deserialize the same JS object